# Why Operations have extra money transaction that are not included in balance calculation?

Tags: operation

I found that some operations have more money transfers that are actually included in the explorer, can somebody explain why?

[This operation](https://tzscan.io/onmqJCqzWtnqKii9oJkkoXeNdm1dX9UZVaH3U6LMKaGoBjWATgH) for example have the following JSON:

```
{
  "protocol": "PsddFKi32cMJ2qPjf43Qv5GDWLDPZb3T3bF6fLKiF5HtvHNU7aP",
  "chain_id": "NetXdQprcVkpaWU",
  "hash": "onmqJCqzWtnqKii9oJkkoXeNdm1dX9UZVaH3U6LMKaGoBjWATgH",
  "branch": "BLakrK2ZhRXb14WBuEAyKMzDdkLq4rz5pSUiB78wXRKnvS3nDnA",
  "contents": [
    {
      "kind": "transaction",
      "source": "KT1RXmLjL8WQz248EFNTB57Nvvy4mgVsdWHp",
      "fee": "1420",
      "counter": "1961",
      "gas_limit": "10300",
      "storage_limit": "300",
      "amount": "325200000",
      "destination": "tz1PLFqDRnDGfPYqjQZFc1dporoB5Z6o61y1",
      "metadata": {
        "balance_updates": [
          {
            "kind": "contract",
            "contract": "KT1RXmLjL8WQz248EFNTB57Nvvy4mgVsdWHp",
            "change": "-1420"
          },
          {
            "kind": "freezer",
            "category": "fees",
            "delegate": "tz1Yju7jmmsaUiG9qQLoYv35v5pHgnWoLWbt",
            "level": 67,
            "change": "1420"
          }
        ],
        "operation_result": {
          "status": "applied",
          "balance_updates": [
            {
              "kind": "contract",
              "contract": "KT1RXmLjL8WQz248EFNTB57Nvvy4mgVsdWHp",
              "change": "-325200000"
            },
            {
              "kind": "contract",
              "contract": "tz1PLFqDRnDGfPYqjQZFc1dporoB5Z6o61y1",
              "change": "325200000"
            },
            {
              "kind": "contract",
              "contract": "KT1RXmLjL8WQz248EFNTB57Nvvy4mgVsdWHp",
              "change": "-257000"
            }
          ],
          "consumed_gas": "10100",
          "allocated_destination_contract": true
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "signature": "sigQCaGncaXLWkCbSu6HxfKucDDHAFFERnxiDJ7s4iB21wqH8enJZYcSCR1ivsLSczE8a3Y5GDUVKCbJyCUm9iSpsLmqcRH3"
}
```

Everything looks fine, however, in operation_result, there are three transfers:

> KT1RXmLjL8WQz248EFNTB57Nvvy4mgVsdWHp -325200000
>       tz1PLFqDRnDGfPYqjQZFc1dporoB5Z6o61y1 +325200000
>       **KT1RXmLjL8WQz248EFNTB57Nvvy4mgVsdWHp -257000**

Fees separately.

Why this -257000 transfer is missing in balance calculation?

I checked some other explorers - they have same trait.

Any reason why?

How to distinguish this ghost transfers that do not happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `257000` µꜩ is "origination burn". Simply put, when creating(or transferring to) a new address, there is a cost and the current value is `257000` µꜩ. Since this is a "burn", it's actually a deflation as no one is the recipient. This burn is mostly to prevent spamming. Creating a KT address has always had such requirement, but for tz address, this is introduced in the [protocol 3 update](https://tezos.gitlab.io/alphanet/protocols/003_PsddFKi3.html?highlight=burn#fix-to-prevent-account-creation-spam).

Comment: Just to clarify, does it means that money actually taken from source account? Because,  blockchain explores simply ignore this "burn" and do not update original balance accordingly.

Comment: Yes, in this case, if you look at the json you posted, it has a `-257000` off of the KT address which is the source address. I'm not sure why the explorer is ignoring the balance change because it should get deducted.